# How do you stop the Identity middleware from redirecting on a 401?

Tags: c#, authorization, identity, middleware

Working with AspNetCore RC2 (and now v1)... using a mix of [JWT bearer tokens](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core) and the Identity middleware for authentication and authorization. Went though the tutorial (linked) and got token authentication and authorization working with the WebAPI.

I need "app.UseIdentity()" in the Startup.cs Configuration in order to use the Identity framework to manage users and roles. The problems is: it's causing the WebAPI to redirect to "account/login" instead of simply returning a 401 (unauthorized) status when an anonymous user tries to hit an endpoint with [Authorize] on it.

I've seen people talk about how to stop this when using cookie authentication, but that doesn't help, as I'm only using tokens.

Can anyone point me in a direction on how to tell the Identity middleware to stop redirecting unauthorized attempts? (If code is needed, let me know.) :)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have stopped the redirect (Startup.cs, ConfigureServices method):

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = false;
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = PathString.Empty;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
});
```

Comment: Actually, just setting `options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge` to `false` stops identity from altering the response and therefore it won't redirect automatically.